# What pattern rules are used as paths in angular service worker configuration files?

Tags: angular, service-worker

Lots of examples or tutorials use this configuration section to explain how Angular service workers can be configured:

```
   {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
```

But I haven't been able to find any documentation about wildcards on strings at the "files" array.

What means that double asterisk on the `assets/**` entry.

What does that double simbol mean?

Where can I find documentation on that pattern so I can use that and other combinations properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's all about "glob" patterns.

> *"Globs" are the patterns you type when you do stuff like ls *.js on the command line, or put build/* in a .gitignore file.*

documentation about the use and shortcuts can be found at the "node-glob" library on github:

https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Maybe tutorial creators should include this information, or references about how-to use this patterns, when blindly copy-pasteing examples to bloat their work.